# How to access hard drive via USB & router on Win10

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, usb-drive

TLDR: I had this working two days ago, my laptop's hard drive crashed & has been replaced, now I can't map to my 8TB drive that's attached to my router via USB.

For months (since Covid started & I've been WFH) I've been using an 8TB drive attached to my router via USB for storage, backup, etc. for my work files.  My hard drive died in my Dell laptop a couple of days ago and has been replaced by IT today.  Now that I have it home, I can't connect to the drive like I had before.  I should be able to just open File Explorer in Win10 and enter \\192.168.1.1 and browse for shares.  I can see that the shares exist on the drive via the router's web interface (Linksys 1900 AC WRT), but I can't get to the drive to access them.  I'm connected to the same network as before (my home WIFI), my Macs and Roku can see the drive no problem, it's just this new install of Win10 on the new drive.

It's been a long day, and I'm bleary eyed, so I know I'm just missing something stupid, but I could use your guy's help figuring out what it is I'm missing.

The error message I get when trying to connect with the UNC above is:

```
Network Error

Windows cannot access \\\192.168.1.1\

Check the spelling of the name.  Otherwise there might be a problem with your

network.  To try to identify & resolve network problems, click Diagnose.  

Details drop down:

Error code 0x80004005

Unspecified error.
```

I'm going to try @rzlvmp suggestion to enable SMB V1 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess No.1

That is possible that your router use samba v1. SMBv1 disabled on new windows versions. But you can [enable](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10) it

Comment: No, that was a typo (I'll edit). Adding the share name doesn't work either.

Comment: what error appears? what windows version was before? what MacOs version did you try?

Comment: That was it, thanks!  Now I need to figure out how to get custom firmware on my router that uses Samba 2.